# Unable to run IRB due to Permission Denied after updating to the latest version of RubyGems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

so I recently updated to the latest version of ruby gems, since I'm thinking of publishing my own. I followed the instructions from the RubyGem guides (http://help.rubygems.org/kb/gemcutter/publishing-your-own-rubygem), particularly running this in my command line:

```
$ sudo gem update --system
```

now whenever i try to open up IRB or run anything ruby related whatsoever, I get the following error message:

```
/Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12 (Errno::EACCES)
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `fu_mkdir'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:221:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `reverse_each'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `block in mkdir_p'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `each'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `mkdir_p'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:210:in `write_gem_make_out'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:132:in `build_error'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:171:in `rescue in build_extension'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:156:in `build_extension'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1436:in `block in build_extensions'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:45:in `use_ui'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `build_extensions'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `block in find_inactive_by_path'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/locale.rb:150:in `block in search_file'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/locale.rb:158:in `block in each_localized_path'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/locale.rb:167:in `each_sublocale'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/locale.rb:157:in `each_localized_path'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/locale.rb:145:in `search_file'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/locale.rb:124:in `find'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/locale.rb:108:in `load'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/locale.rb:32:in `initialize'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/init.rb:114:in `new'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/init.rb:114:in `init_config'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/init.rb:16:in `setup'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:53:in `start'
from /Users/sunnyisrani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Try manually downloading and installing the latest rubygems (v2.1.11) from http://rubygems.org/pages/download. (Have heard more complaints recently with gem update --system, not sure what's messed up)

Comment: I would suggest installing rvm and using that. Try googling for a tutorial on how to install it...

Answer (score 0):

Fwiw, I had a similar problem where `irb` was complaining about permissions errors.

Although I did not want to have to `sudo` to `root` each time I used `irb`, I did try `sudo`'ing to root just to see if it would work and it worked fine.

After that, I exited from root, back to my regular login, and ran `irb` again and it worked fine.